# Gmail app repeatedly notify for the same email

Tags: gmail, push-notifications

When I receive an email, there will be a push notifcation from the Gmail app. If I leave it unattended, it will pop up again and again.
I set the sync frequency at every 15 minutes in order to get notified as soon as possible. However, it seems that every time the account syncs, it will notify me about any unread emails. The notification will just keep popping up until I read the email. Is there a way to only notify once for each unread email?
I found something called "Notify once" in the gmail account settings, but not in other accounts' settings (like outlook accounts).

Comment: Are you talking about a gmail mail account or an third party IMAP/POP3 account configured in GMail app?

Comment: I'm talking about all accounts I set up in the Gmail app. It seems to be an issue with the app. The Outlook app seems not to have this issue (same email accounts).